# Windows username not being passed to Oracle DB?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, iis, oracle-manageddataaccess

I'm using the Oracle ManagedDataAccess driver to access a database from a .NET Web Application. When running it locally under IIS Express as windows user x this works fine, but when I publish my site to another server with IIS I get error

ORA-01017: Invalid username/password; login denied

I viewed attempted logins from Oracle as outlined [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_tracking_counting_failed_logon_signon_attempts.htm). Where logins were successful from IIS I can see my windows username listed, OPS$(USERNAME).

Interestingly, where logins are unsuccessful, from IIS, I see the wrong username being passed - Username = OPS$(NAME_OF_MY_WEB_APPLICATION). I have no idea where it is getting the idea to substitute the name of the application as a username.

My connection string is the same for both environments:
**User ID=/**;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP))(HOST=...(PORT=1521)(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=...)));

Comment: Is NTLM (windows) authentication activated on that site and server ? anonymous access should be deactivated. Check IIS settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out impersonation was disabled in IIS, adding

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

to my web.config solved the issue. My Oracle driver was using the name of the app pool user which was the same as my web application.